# Управление содержимым div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function toggle(imgElem, divId) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var divElem = document.getElementById(divId);
    if (divElem.className == "closed") {
      divElem.className = "opened";
      document.getElementById("all_projects");
    } else {
      divElem.className = "closed";
      document.getElementById("all_projects");
    }
  }
}

function toggle(imgElem, divId) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var divElem = document.getElementById(divId);
    if (divElem.className == "closed") {
      divElem.className = "opened";
      document.getElementById("pohotography");
    } else {
      divElem.className = "closed";
      document.getElementById("pohotography");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.closed {
  display: none;
}

.opened {
  color: red;
}

.closed_1 {
  display: none;
}

.opened_1 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption_and_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="all_projects" onclick="toggle(this,'openbox')">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a id="pohotography" onclick="toggle(this,'openbox_1')">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="openbox" class="closed">
  <p>Hallo weld!</p>
</div>
<div id="openbox_1" class="closed_1">
  <p>Hi!</p>
</div>
```

Имеется три пункта меню на сайте. Нужно кликая по ним менять содержимое div. Например:

- ссылка на фотоальбом - показать фотоальбом
- ссылка на портфолио - показать портфолио

и т.д..
При этом скрыв все другие div. Пока код у меня готов только на скрыть-показать по клику содержимое div. Приходит на ум, просто копировать для каждого элемента функцию, но это конечно не верный подход.

Подскажите решение.

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос виджет с тем что у вас есть на данный момент.

Comment: гугли. То что ты ищещь называется - аккордеон. Его вообще без JS можно сделать

Comment: Идея такая делаете три div-a, при клике на меню скрываете все три, и показываете тоот один который ассоциирован с кнопкой меню.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790869/286129 - по этой ссылке возьмите код и продебажьте в браузере. Удачи.

Comment: Mursalov Oleg, Огромное спасибо, вопрос решён!

Answer (score 2):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('open')].forEach((s, i) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('open')].forEach((a, l) => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('openBox')[l].classList.remove('active');
      document.getElementsByClassName('open')[l].classList.remove('openActive');
    })
    document.getElementsByClassName('openBox')[i].classList.add('active');
    s.classList.add('openActive');
  })
})
```

```css
.openActive {
  color: red;
}

.openBox {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.openBox.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption_and_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="open">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a class="open">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="openbox" class="openBox">
  <p>Hallo weld!</p>
</div>
<div id="openbox_1" class="openBox">
  <p>Hi!</p>
</div>
```